# When other observation become to NA when i get some obs under conditions from data frame

Tags: r, read.csv

First of all, i download a csv file from url

```
fileurl<-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv"

week3<-download.file(fileurl,destfile="./week3.csv",method="curl")
```

Then use read.csv to turn into data frame 
    week31<-read.csv("week3.csv",header=TRUE)

[image]

After that, i need to extract the observation, when column ACR=3 and AGS=6

```
agricultureLogical2<-week31[(week31$ACR==3 & week31$AGS==6),]
```

but the result is not looking good, the value of other observation that don't meet the condition under every column becomes NA, why?

[image]

Comment: It is likely that your data contains NAs. You should add `!is.na()` to your selection criteria: `week31[(week31$ACR==3 & week31$AGS==6) & !is.na(week31$ACR), & !is.na(week31$AGS),]`

Comment: Thanks, you code did work, but would you have a look at the data frame just after used the read.csv function. The value of the most observation under each column is not NA, but after used my code, it turned into NA, that's why i ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use subset function followed by %in% which returns if there is a match

```
agricultureLogical2 <- subset(week31, ACR%in%3 & AGS%in%6 ,]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why my method is not accurate? Thanks!